# check sum error on Nodemcu 0.9 (esp 8266 wifi )

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I purchased a Nodemcu 0.9, it prints gibberish at 9600 or 115200 baud rates.
But at 74880 baud rate I get this error

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0xef
csum 0xef
csum err
ets_main.c
```

If someone knows how to correct this please respond .

Comment: what application is uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, its a cheap Chinese board, and the code is erased after uploaded the fault is with the Nodemcu board,

The proper generic one should work with 9600 baud rate.

Comment: and what did you upload?